# Submit form (Ajax style) when a radio button is selected -- Struts2

Tags: struts2, refresh, radio-button

In Struts2 I wanted to refresh(submit) a portion of page on selection of a radio button (Ajax) retaining all the rows in table of rows. Can someone please help with the code for this.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario which you have mentioned can be implemented using AJAX. Try [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)

[Here](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/examples/index.html) are some examples which shows what you can do with DWR

Comment: VinAy thank you for your reply, I tried enquiring about DWR, but our org don't have that as standard, so I did not tried.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the showcase for the [Struts2 jquery Plugin](http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action).

Go to "Ajax Form" -> "Buttonset / Radio Buttons" this is an example for an AJAX Submit triggered by an radio button.